# How to write from Spark strucutred streaming to RDMS? What is inside foreach row?

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

It is [written in documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreach), that one can write rows to database with `foreach` against `writeStream`

```
def process_row(row):
    # Write row to storage
    pass

query = streamingDF.writeStream.foreach(process_row).start()
```

What is not written, is what is inside `row`? How can I process it without this knowledge?

---

Currently I wrote

```
df = df... # something

def write_row(row):

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=config["jdbc"]["host"],
        port=config["jdbc"]["port"],
        user=config["jdbc"]["user"],
        password=config["jdbc"]["password"],
        database=config["jdbc"]["database"],
    )

    dbtable = ...

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    sql = f"INSERT INTO {dbtable} (user_id, carName) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    val = (352, "Sample")
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)

    mydb.commit()


query = df \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode('update') \
    .foreach(write_row) \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't write anything. Function `write_row` itself works and writes sample row. When inside `foreach`, it doesn't.

If error occurs in this function, how would I know it?

---

I rewrote according to @AlexOtt.

If I run this

```
def foreach_batch_function(df1, epoch_id):
    df1.write.format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", "jdbc:mariadb://IPADDRESS/database") \
        .option("dbtable", "pysparktest") \
        .option("user", config["jdbc"]["user"]) \
        .option("password", config["jdbc"]["password"]) \
        .option("driver", "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver") \
        .save()
```

or with option

```
.option("createTableColumnTypes", "cnt int, minBestLapTime double, trackName varchar(64), trackVersion varchar(64), carClass varchar(64), carName varchar(64), carVersion varchar(64)") \
```

while table does not exist, it fails with SQL syntax error. And if table already exists, it fails saying "table exists".

Is it possible to populate existing table?

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use [foreachBatch](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch) instead - in this case you can just use the standard [Spark JDBC operations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html), something like this:

```py
def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
  df.write.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "your_driver") \
    .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
    .option("user", "username") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .save()
  
df.writeStream.foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).start()
```

Comment: How will it map hierarchical columns of Spark with one-level columns of RDMS?

Comment: It will not map them automatically, but you can just use Spark APIs to create a dataframe that has a structure matching database structure (either inside `foreach_batch_function` or in the stream).  For example if you have a struct column with name `struct`, and you want to promote its fields to top-level, then you can do `select("*", "struct.*").drop("strunct")` - that's just normal Spark API.  But it will be much more efficient than doing inserts "manually"